# How to take modulus of a large value stored in array?

Tags: c, arrays, modulus

Suppose I have a integer array containing digits and I want to take modulus of value stored in it, i.e

```
 int a[36]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

and convert it into a number like `987654321987654321987654321987654321`.

In C language `long long int` permits only 10^18. I want to take modulus with 10^9+7. How can i do that?

Program:

```
int main()
{
int a[36]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
long long int temp=0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<36;i++)
{
     temp=temp+a[i]*pow(10,i);
}
temp=temp%1000000007;
printf("%lld",temp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Switch to a bignum library,  don't use arrays to try and emulate big numbers.

Comment: Is it related to some SPOJ problem? In this case I believe you are not telling us everything.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  No it is not related to SPOJ problem but i need to use it somewhere??

Comment: @VasuDevGarg Because if it is related to some specific problem, it could have some extra information that might lead to more optimal solution. But if it is not - disregard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 36 decimal digits is too much for a typical `long long`, you need to perform your modulus operation during the conversion:

```
int a[36]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
long long int temp=0;
for(int i=35 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    temp = 10*temp + a[i];
    temp %= 1000000007;
}
printf("%lld",temp);
```

I made two changes to your code:

- **Fixed the way you convert an array of digits to a number** - your code used `pow`, and treated digits at higher indexes as higher-order digits. This creates precision problems once you get past the highest power of ten that can be represented as `double`.
- **Moved the `%=` into the loop** - your code does not let the number overflow by keeping the value in the range from 0 to 1000000006, inclusive.

Running this code [produces](http://ideone.com/F5iPxz) the same value that you would obtain with a library that supports arbitrary precision of integers (I used Java `BigInteger` [here](http://ideone.com/ltvYll)).

Comment: the idiom `for (int i=35 ; i >= 0 ; i--) { ... }` is error prone: the correct type for `i` should be `size_t` and the initial value should be `sizeof a / sizeof *a` or at worst the same magic constant as used for the length of `a`. I would suggest: `for (size_t i=36 ; i-- > 0 ; ) { ... }`

Comment: @chqrlie Moving side effects into the condition for the loop does the trick, but its readability suffers tremendously, especially to an untrained reader. I would let OP beautify his own code to his own liking: the important point is to do the `%=`s inside the loop, and to not use `pow` which loses precision when `i` gets too high.

Comment: I fully agree regarding the main computation issue. As for the downward loop, both approaches are equally inelegant, an alternative is to move the decrement to the body eg: `temp = 10*temp + a[--i];`, but that's looks even worse.